# How to coded reference from an APA a reference in excel?

Tags: regex, google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

I have a database with APA references in a column like this one (let's sake it's in A6 for the sake of our example) in Google Sheets (online reproducibility aimed)

> `Smith (2010) Assessing the Impact of Aimhigher Kent and Medway`

I would like to create a new code column with just the last name of the first author and the date. For our example, that would be

> `Smith2010`

I tried things like

> =REGEXEXTRACT(A6; "\w.(\d\d\d\d)")

but it doesn't work. Could you help me please in this very low-level issue?

Thanks in advance,

Comment: Changed it ! Sorry I'm very new :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One option is to use REGEXREPLACE with 2 capturing groups, and use those groups in the replacement.

```
^[^\S\r\n]*(\w+)[^()\r\n]+\((\d{4})\).*
```

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/jym38Y/1)

```
=REGEXREPLACE(A6; "^[^\S\r\n]*(\w+)[^()\r\n]+\((\d{4})\).*"; "$1$2")
```

[image]

Comment: @JvdV Ah, maybe you are right. I focussed on the function REGEXEXTRACT. If I am wrong I will remove the answer.

Comment: Huuum yeah this code doesn't work for me, it just returns the same expression that on A6... I think the last part `"$1$2' doesn't work... Does anybody know how to merge the 2 extracted expressions together?

Comment: This `=REGEXEXTRACT( A6; "^(\w+) \((\d{4})\).*")`
 doesn't work either

Comment: @LaudineCarbuccia Are you using Excel or Google sheets?

Comment: Google Sheets :)

Comment: I pasted that the sentence from the question in A6, and for B6 I used the REGEXREPLACE command, just as in the screenshot.

Comment: Hi, thanks so much. I tried to send a screenshot but failed... I don't get what is wrong with my sentence as I exactly pasted yours...

Comment: @LaudineCarbuccia Is the sentence the same as in this regex demo? https://regex101.com/r/KHT5sJ/1 So no spaces before? So exactly `Smith (2010) Assessing the Impact of Aimhigher Kent and Medway`

Comment: have you tried the formula by @Thefourthbird adjasted to your locale? `=REGEXREPLACE(A6; "^(\w+) \((\d{4})\).*"; "$1$2")`

Comment: Well my other example are more or less the same e.g. `
Aldana, U. S., Mayer, A. P., & Ee, J. (2019). The Impact of the IB Diploma Programme on Student High School and Postsecondary Experiences: US Public Schools Serving Students from Low-Income Households`

Comment: When I write this in B5 `=REGEXREPLACE(A5; "^(\w+) \((\d{4})\).*"; "$1$2")` I got this as an output `Aldana, U. S., Mayer, A. P., & Ee, J. (2019). The Impact of the IB Diploma Programme on Student High School and Postsecondary Experiences: US Public Schools Serving Students from Low-Income Households.` Which is exactly the same thing as in A5

Comment: Try it like this `^[^\S\r\n]*([^()\r\n]+) \((\d{4})\).*` See https://regex101.com/r/wAbCyD/1

Comment: I created a new Sheet in case you wanna see it for yourself :)  https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1ewyPclWf9ZDgSvzCFbG9Ik0WtY6TbHwCI4pvz0w-Ozo/edit?usp=sharing

Comment: `^[^\S\r\n]*([^()\r\n]+) \((\d{4})\).*`this is ways better, but I have all the authors name while I would like just the last name of the first author :(

Comment: Like this? https://regex101.com/r/VT4xS9/1 Matching names can be very tricky

Comment: YEEEEES this one works `=REGEXREPLACE(A5; "^[^\S\r\n]*?(\w+)[^()\r\n]+\((\d{4})\).*"; "$1$2")` You can see I removed the bracket between * and ? because my spread sheet cuts the code there otherwise... THANKS !

Comment: @LaudineCarbuccia Glad it works for you :-)  I will update the answer.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to @The fourth bird the solution is:

```
> =REGEXREPLACE(A6; "^[^\S\r\n]*?(\w+)[^()\r\n]+\((\d{4})\).*"; "$1$2")
```

Thanks a lot for the ones who helped !!